# Ebay API returns "Service operation is unknown" and "Missing SOA operation name header" errors when using PHP

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

I'd like to make a soap call to the eBay api and finds products by keywords. With the help of [eBay documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html) and other online resources, I came up with this code:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl');
$soap_headers = array(
    new \SoapHeader('X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME', 'findItemsByKeywords'),
    new \SoapHeader('X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION', '1.3.0'),
    new \SoapHeader('X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT', 'XML'),
    new \SoapHeader('X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID', 'EBAY-US'),
    new \SoapHeader('X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME', '<there would be the key>'),
);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_headers);

// Call wsdl function
$result = $client->__soapCall("findItemsByKeywords", array("keywords" => "Potter"));
```

However, this code results in an error:
**"Service operation is unknown,
500 Internal Server Error - SoapFault"**

I tried changing the first line into this (don't know why it should make a difference, but I saw it somewhere):

```
$client = new \SoapClient(NULL, array(
"location" => 'http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1', 
'uri' => 'http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1')
);
```

And now this result in this error: **Missing SOA operation name header,
500 Internal Server Error - SoapFault**

Does anybody know what causes these errors to occur and how to fix them?

Thank you, Mike!

Comment: @Cray I am sorry I rejected your edit.  I thought it was an audit.  I apologize for this.  Your edit isn't spam or vandalism at all.  I will try to get less sensitive with audits in future.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works.

```
define('APP_ID', '*** Your App ID ***');
$wsdl = 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl';
// For sandbox
$endpoint_uri = 'http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
// For production
//$endpoint_uri = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

// We'll use this namespace explicitly for the 'keywords' tag,
// because the SoapClient doesn't apply it automatically.
$ns = 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services';
// The SOAP function
$operation = 'findItemsByKeywords';

$http_headers = implode(PHP_EOL, [
  "X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: $operation",
  "X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: " . APP_ID,
]);

$options = [
  'trace' => true,
  'cache' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'location' => $endpoint_uri,
  //'uri' => 'ns1',
  'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => $http_headers,
    ]
  ]),
];

$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

try {
  $wrapper = new StdClass;
  $wrapper->keywords = new SoapVar('harry potter', XSD_STRING,
    null, null, null, $ns);

  $result = $client->$operation(new SoapVar($wrapper, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
  var_dump($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As already mentioned, one of the issues is that you pass `X-EBAY-SOA-*` values as *SOAP* headers. The [service expects](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html#callstruct) them as *HTTP* headers:

> **HTTP Headers or URL Parameters**—Each Finding API call requires certain
>   HTTP headers or URL parameters. For example, you must specify your
>   AppID in the `X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME` header or `SECURITY-APPNAME`
>   URL parameter. Similarly, you must always specify the call name in the
>   `X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME` header or `OPERATION-NAME` URL parameter.
>   Other headers are optional or conditionally required.

The second issue is that the [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) `location` option is not specified. It should contain an URI to one of the  [service endpoints](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html#endpt). Otherwise, the API returns `Service operation  is unknown` error.

Finally, the `SoapClient` doesn't put the `keywords` into Ebay's namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
      <keywords>harry potter</keywords>
    </ns1:findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As a result, the API returns an error: `Keywords value required.`. So I've specified the namespace for the `keywords` tag explicitly.

Also note the use of different endpoint URIs for sandbox and for production.

Comment: Thank you for the woking code and explanation! Finally I've been able to make it run!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the service expects **HTTP** Headers (or query string parameters, apparently, by reading their guide a bit).

With `__setSoapHeaders` you are, well, setting **SOAP** Headers.

Try this, for instance

```
$wsdl = 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl';

$appID = 'YOUR KEY/ID';

$headers = implode(PHP_EOL, [
  "X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsByKeywords",
  "X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: $appID"
]);

$options = [
  'trace' => true,
  'cache' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
      'header' => $headers
    ]
  ]),
];

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$response = $client->findItemsByKeywords([
  'keywords' => 'Potter'
]);
```

Comment: Hi Alejadro. I tried it and the code was failing in authentication, so I discovered that it is necessary to add commas between the headers. Anyways, now there is the same error as before: "Service operation findItemsByKeywords, is unknown" and it is failing on the _soapCall(..) method.

Comment: @Mike Yes, because of the comma, the service is trying to find `findItemsByKeywords,` now. Remove the comma. Headers should be separated by new line characters. See updated answer